# htaccess lowercase without RewriteMap

Tags: .htaccess

I need to rewrite all urls to lowercase but I don't have access to the httpd.conf to add RewriteMap. Is there a way to do an .htaccess rewrite to lowercase without RewriteMap? the current code below that I have tried is producing a internal error/500

```
#RewriteEngine On
#RewriteMap lowercase int:tolower
#RewriteCond $1 [A-Z]
#RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /${lowercase:$1} [R=303,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteMap  lc int:tolower
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteRule (.*) ${lc:$1} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
CheckSpelling On
CheckCaseOnly On
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule "(.*)A(.*)" "$1a$2" [N,R]
RewriteRule "(.*)B(.*)" "$1b$2" [N,R]
RewriteRule "(.*)C(.*)" "$1c$2" [N,R]
RewriteRule "(.*)D(.*)" "$1d$2" [N,R]
RewriteRule "(.*)E(.*)" "$1e$2" [N,R]
RewriteRule "(.*)F(.*)" "$1f$2" [N,R]
RewriteRule "(.*)G(.*)" "$1g$2" [N,R]
RewriteRule "(.*)H(.*)" "$1h$2" [N,R]
RewriteRule "(.*)I(.*)" "$1i$2" [N,R]
RewriteRule "(.*)J(.*)" "$1j$2" [N,R]
RewriteRule "(.*)K(.*)" "$1k$2" [N,R]
RewriteRule "(.*)L(.*)" "$1l$2" [N,R]
RewriteRule "(.*)M(.*)" "$1m$2" [N,R]
RewriteRule "(.*)N(.*)" "$1n$2" [N,R]
RewriteRule "(.*)O(.*)" "$1o$2" [N,R]
RewriteRule "(.*)P(.*)" "$1p$2" [N,R]
RewriteRule "(.*)Q(.*)" "$1q$2" [N,R]
RewriteRule "(.*)R(.*)" "$1r$2" [N,R]
RewriteRule "(.*)S(.*)" "$1s$2" [N,R]
RewriteRule "(.*)T(.*)" "$1t$2" [N,R]
RewriteRule "(.*)U(.*)" "$1u$2" [N,R]
RewriteRule "(.*)V(.*)" "$1v$2" [N,R]
RewriteRule "(.*)W(.*)" "$1w$2" [N,R]
RewriteRule "(.*)X(.*)" "$1x$2" [N,R]
RewriteRule "(.*)Y(.*)" "$1y$2" [N,R]
RewriteRule "(.*)Z(.*)" "$1z$2" [N,R]
```